# realmd - Allow AD Group

Tags: centos, active-directory

I have a CentOS machine which I have successfully connected to a Windows AD. I can ssh login with any user existing in the AD on the CentOS client. Now I want to permit only a specific AD group to login (admins), but it is not working. First, I am disabling login with

```
realm deny -R mydomain.local -a
```

Works. Second I want to allow a specific group, which is, comming from AD:

```
distinguishedName: CN=Admins,OU=Users-All,OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local
```

I have used two approaches, but none of them seems to work:

```
realm permit -g Admins

realm permit -g 'mydomain.local\\Users\Users-All\Admins'
```

Since I'm pretty new to AD with linux, any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Using the ad_access_filter in sssl.conf, the linux computer has to have the permissions to read the user object in the AD. After talking to our system admin he has granted the permission and now it works... :)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by editing  `/etc/security/pam_winbind.conf`

```
require_membership_of = S-1-5-21-361205316-2009527927-3895120483-1111,localgroup1
```

you can figure out S-1-... string using `wbinfo -G "User all"`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using realm to configure sssd, no samba...